# Undefined property: stdClass, HasOne datas

Tags: php, laravel

I can't get HasOne data from database. How can i do?

I can get other datas.

Controller;

```php
$gelensunucu = Request::get('gelensunucu');
$gelenrol = Request::get('gelenrol');
$gelenkume = Request::get('gelenkume');

$veriler = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw("*"))
    ->where('kume_id', '=', $gelenkume)
    ->where('rol_id', '=', $gelenrol)
    ->where('sunucu_id', '=', $gelensunucu)
    ->get();

return view('home')->with('veriler', $veriler);
```

User Model;

```php
protected $fillable = [ 'sunucu_id', 'rol_id',  'kume_id', 'tecrube' ...]

    public function kumeler()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\kumeler','id','kume_id');
    }

    public function roller()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\roller','id','rol_id');
    }

    public function sunucular()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\sunucular','id','sunucu_id');
    }
```

Other Models;

```php
class sunucular extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sunucular';
}
```

> Undefined property: stdClass::$sunucular (0)

Comment: can you update your question with sunucu, user, kume and rol Models, please

Comment: What about define your `hasOne` relation on `user` model? Than you get data calling `$user->yourRelationNameHere`

Comment: And please, update your question with more info, as suggested by @Thamerbelfkih

Comment: Other models also look like, thank for answers @Thamerbelfkih

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access relationships when you use the Model `User`. Right now, you're calling the following:

```
$veriler = DB::table('users')...->get();
```

The result of this query is a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects, and not a `Collection` of `User` model instances. Therefore, you can't call something like `$user->sunucular` as the default `stdClass` objects does not have a property/method called `sunucular`. To fix this, **use your `User` model**:

```
$veriler = User::where('kume_id', '=', $gelenkume)
->where('rol_id', '=', $gelenrol)
->where('sunucu_id', '=', $gelensunucu)
->get();

// Note:: You don't need to call `->select(DB::raw("*"))`; it's redundant.
```

Also, make sure your user is property imported in your Controller:

```
user App\User;
```

Or access via namespace:

```
$veriler = \App\User::...->get();
```

Either way, now you will have a `Collection` of `User` model instances, which have the relationships available.

In summary, you can't use `DB::table()` if you want to access relationships; they are defined on the `User` model, and need to be queried in a way that allows access.